# AirWatch API to refresh Android app automatically

Tags: android, flutter, refresh, vmware, airwatch

I want to implement auto-refresh feature(call few services) in android app. Within the given duration(ex. 30 sec) I want to refresh app periodically.

I searched in [Airwatch rest API list](https://resources.workspaceone.com/view/zv5cgwjrcv972rd6fmml/en) but I didn't get any API name. Can any one suggest me if it is available or not in the given list for the same task.